# Configuring nginx but apache httpd not working

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, docker-compose, httpd.conf

I am trying to add nginx to my dockerized application. I have this as my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # ports:
    #   - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/app/shared
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://db:27017/db_name
      - PORT=3001
      - FE_ADDRESS=http://192.168.1.152:3000
      - SHARE=/app/shared

  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  shared:
    image: httpd:2.4
    ports:
      - 2020:80
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
    restart: always

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - app
      - shared
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 3050:90
```

I left shared service port mapping so I am sure that service is working. I am accessing it on localhost:2020. Here is the .conf file of nginx:

```
upstream app {
    server app:3001;
}

upstream shared {
    server shared:80;
}

server {
    listen 90;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    location /shared {
        proxy_pass http://shared;
    }
}
```

I am making shared and app as upstream blocks so I can host them on specific locations. For app everyting works OK and on localhost:3050/ I see my node.js application. The problem is when I try to access localhost:3050/shared I am automatically redirected to localhost:90/shared and nothing is shown. What could be the problem and how I can setup my apache to work on this location? Should I have some additional configuration for apache as I am quite now to nginx? Or it is easier to make nginx to serve static directory? I am using this directory in app service - I upload files there.

UPDATE:
I logged in the nginx container and executed:

```
curl http://shared
```

This is what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /</h1>
<ul><li><a href=".gitkeep"> .gitkeep</a></li>
<li><a href="answers/"> answers/</a></li>
<li><a href="avatars/"> avatars/</a></li>
<li><a href="cases/"> cases/</a></li>
<li><a href="comments/"> comments/</a></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

So inside nginx it is possible to see the shared service.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on idea to have Apache and changed default.conf:

```
upstream app {
    server app:3001;
}

server {
    listen 90;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
    }

    location /shared/ {
        alias /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/;
        autoindex on;

    }
}
```

Then I added volumes in nginx service:

```
nginx:
    depends_on:
      - app
      # - shared
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server/nginx
    ports:
      - 3050:90
    volumes:
      - ./server/shared:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Now it is working OK but I would appreciate if there is answer how to use apache httpd.